# Add Buttons to Navigation Bar that are aligned with the Title

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have this navigation title, and I tried to align some buttons with it using .toolbar. But Whenever I lower it with some extra padding on the top (so that they can be aligned horizontally) the buttons stop being able to be clicked. Is there some kind of area around the navigationTitle where I can't hit buttons? How do I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The button is only tappable in the navigation bar area. In your screenshot I don't think you need to use NavigationView, just a VStack with a Text as title and some buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can add views including buttons to the Navigation bar using `.naivgationBarItems(leading: View?, center: View?, trailing: View?)`